# ExtJs doesn't load data to a form using ext.data.store

Tags: javascript, json, url, extjs4.2

i need to load the data from a json object in to the form panel when the form is loaded
my code is like this

this is my data model

```
Ext.define('Contact', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
fields : [ {
    name : 'first',
    mapping : 'name.first'
}, {
    name : 'last',
    mapping : 'name.last'
}, 'company', 'email', {
    name : 'dob',
    type : 'date',
    dateFormat : 'm/d/Y'
} ]
```

});

and this is my data store

```
var store = Ext
    .create(
            'Ext.data.Store',
            {
                // alert("inside")
                // id: 'store',
                model : 'Contact',
                proxy : {
                    type : 'ajax',
                    url : 'http://localhost:8090/extjs-crud-grid-spring-hibernate/contact/view.action',
                    reader : 'json',
                    root : 'contact'
                },
                autoLoad : true
            });
```

and this is my form panel

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title : 'Simple Form with FieldSets',
    labelWidth : 75, // label settings here cascade unless
    // overridden
    // url : 'save-form.php',
    frame : true,
    bodyStyle : 'padding:5px 5px 0',
    width : 340,
    bodyPadding : 5,

    layout : 'anchor', // arrange fieldsets side by side
    items : [ {
        xtype : 'fieldset',
        title : 'Contact Information',
        defaultType : 'textfield',
        defaults : {
            width : 280
        },
        items : [ {
            fieldLabel : 'First Name',
            emptyText : 'First Name',
            name : 'first'
        }, {
            fieldLabel : 'Last Name',
            emptyText : 'Last Name',
            name : 'last'
        }, {
            fieldLabel : 'Company',
            name : 'company'
        }, {
            fieldLabel : 'Email',
            name : 'email',
            vtype : 'email'
        }, {
            xtype : 'datefield',
            fieldLabel : 'Date of Birth',
            name : 'dob',
            allowBlank : false,
            maxValue : new Date()
        } ]
    } ],    
    renderTo : Ext.getBody()
}); 
var record = store.getAt(0);

formPanel.getForm().loadRecord(record);
```

});

and this is my json format

```
{
  "contact": {
    "name": {
      "first": "Aaron",
      "last": "Conran"
    },
    "company": "Ext JS",
    "email": "support@sencha.com",
    "state": "OH",
    "dob": "04/15/2007"
  }
}
```

when i try to put this line "formPanel.getForm().loadRecord(record)"
it gives me this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getData' of undefined "
as well as this doesn't load the data in to the form panel when loaded

hope that anybody can help me

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting data in record variable. Please refer below example...

Instances of this class are only created by a Form when loading.

```
Response Packet Criteria
```

A response packet must contain:

- success property : Boolean
- data property : Object

The data property contains the values of Fields to load. The individual value object for each Field is passed to the Field's setValue method.

`JSON Packets`

By default, response packets are assumed to be JSON, so for the following form load call:

```
var myFormPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    title: 'Client and routing info',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'Client',
        name: 'clientName'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Port of loading',
        name: 'portOfLoading'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Port of discharge',
        name: 'portOfDischarge'
    }]
});
myFormPanel.getForm().load({
    url: '/getRoutingInfo.php',
    params: {
        consignmentRef: myConsignmentRef
    },
    failure: function(form, action) {
        Ext.Msg.alert("Load failed", action.result.errorMessage);
    }
});
```

a success response packet may look like this:

```
{
    success: true,
    data: {
        clientName: "Fred. Olsen Lines",
        portOfLoading: "FXT",
        portOfDischarge: "OSL"
    }
}
```

while a failure response packet may look like this:

```
{
    success: false,
    errorMessage: "Consignment reference not found"
}
```

Other data may be placed into the response for processing the Form's callback or event handler methods. The object decoded from this JSON is available in the `result` property.

Comment: Yes im already getting the data in to the result variable i just try to print it using,                                                                                                                                                                   for(var i in records[0].data){          alert(i + ": " + records[0].data[i]);           }